# Finding the file explorer process windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows

This program organizes desktop windows.

It works for all programs, apart from file explorer windows. When I select the explorer.exe process individually it still is unable to manipulate the file explorer window.

The process finding system:

```
foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
            {
                //stuff
            }
        }
```

Code for moving the windows:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int Width, int Height, bool Repaint);

    public void MoveWindow()
    {
        MoveWindow(handle, (int)x, (int)y, (int)width, (int)height, true);
    }
```

Does anyone know how to make it target a file explorer window?

Thnx to anyone who can help :)

Comment: Is accessing windows via `Process` an important part of this? Because if not, you should be looking at something like [`EnumWindows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows)

Comment: I will take a look at that, I'd prefer using processes, but if that works I could try it

Comment: No, it looks like EnumWindows returns too many non-windows to be usefull